# Retrieve and display only one of the same entries from wordpress database

Tags: database, wordpress

I want to display only one of multiple same entries in wordpress. For example;

```
ID
1
1
5
3
2
5
1
2
3
3
```

is my table and i want to retrieve and display it as;

```
ID = 1, 2, 3, 5
```

all the same values displayed once and the other same values are not displayed.

I have tried below code to display as I want;

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits', OBJECT );
```

but it outputs "Array"

Then I tried this one;

```
$results = $wpdb->query( 'SELECT DISTINCT field_name FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits', OBJECT );
```

and it showed-up the number of entries (output = 4)

How can I get this work?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: what are the fields you are trying to loop, posts?

Comment: @nunorbatista it is a custom table created by the plugin.

Comment: You should be able to eliminate duplicates by using array_unique http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: @nunorbatista Thank you for your messages. I could manage to get what i want. The solution is; $i=0;
while ($i<count($results)){
echo $results[$i]->field_name.'</a><br />';
$i++;
}